# Include an "at" symbol ("@") in a text cell

Tags: libreoffice, spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc, escape-characters

I'm organizing some stuff in a spreadsheet. None of it should be interpreted as anything other than than text, but it does contain a lot of non-alphanumeric characters.

If I include the character `@` in a cell, then that whole word turns blue, and I can no longer delete/change characters within the word. The whole word acts like a single character. Also while I'm editing that cell's contents, the word will have a grey background, making it *very* hard to read.

[image: Four spreadsheet cells. The first says "this: B@0A is wrong". The "B@0A" is blue.]
(My cursor is in the last of those cells, it just doesn't show up in the screenshot.)

What is this?
How do I stop it?

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Go to Tools -> AutoCorrect Options -> Options
2. Uncheck `URL Recognition`
3. Press OK.

[image: AutoCorrect]

Comment: Thanks! Now I have to remember I did this next time I copy-paste a link and it's not clickable :)